# Android support for classful Qdisc 'Prio'

Tags: android, linux, performance, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was trying to use traffic control options to redirect traffic from one interface to another on my Android phone.

On trying the command,

```
tc qdisc add dev wlan0 root handle 1: prio
```

I get the following error

```
Android does not support qdisc 'prio'
```

- Is there any way in which I can get **`prio`** qdisc support in Android?
- What could be my other options if Android does not support **`prio`** qdisc?
- Also overall does Android support classful qdiscs?

Comment: my device is using kernel version 3.0.31  and android version 4.1.2

Comment: Hey! I accidently run `tc qdisc add dev wlan0 root handle 1: prio`. Now my Network manager is crashing.. How to undo it?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking into this now, Android developers actually hardcoded specific modules into tc and left many/most of them out, including prio.  If you look into the tc.c file located at [/external/iproute2/tc/tc.c](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/external/iproute2/tc/tc.c#107)  (linked to kitkat) of AOSP from root, you'll see that they hardcode specific qdisc types into the check:

```
#ifdef ANDROID
    if (!strcmp(str, "cbq"))
        return &cbq_qdisc_util;
    else if (!strcmp(str, "htb"))
        return &htb_qdisc_util;
    else if (!strcmp(str, "ingress"))
        return &ingress_qdisc_util;
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Android does not support qdisc '%s'\n", str);
        return NULL;
    }
#endif
```

I found a commit at cynaogenmod that actually patched these files to bring back the remaining functionality, like prio.  You can find that code commit [here](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/14077/1) (download the diff to patch).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

**`CONFIG_NET_SCH_PRIO`** enables support for `prio` qdisc in the Linux kernel. Most probably this was NOT enabled when your kernel was built. It is listed in the Linux kernel configuration tree under :

```
-> Networking support
  -> Networking options
    -> QoS and/or fair queueing 
      -> Multi Band Priority Queueing (PRIO)
```